# How to calculate determinant of matrix with 9's everywhere off-diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I need help about this question for my algebra exam. I would be very thankful if someone could help me solve this. I should calculate determinant of this $n \times n$-matrix:
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 9 & \cdots & 9 \\
    9 & 2 & \cdots & 9 \\
    9 & 9 & \cdots & 9 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    9 & 9 & \cdots & n \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $n$ is a nonnegative integer.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing very special about $9$, so let's consider the corresponding problem for matrices with off-diagonal elements $q$ and diagonal elements $1,2,\ldots, n$.
Subtract the top row from each other row without changing the determinant: you get

$$ \pmatrix{1   & q & q & \ldots & q\cr
            q-1 & 2-q & 0 & \ldots & 0\cr
            q-1 & 0 & 3-q & \ldots & 0\cr
            \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \cr
            q-1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & n-q\cr} $$
Now use Leibniz's formula for the determinant.  A term that avoids all the zero entries will be either the product $(2-q)(3-q)\ldots (n-q)$ of all the diagonal elements, or
it will have one of the $q-1$'s (say in row $i$), the corresponding $q$ in column $i$, and the diagonal elements except for $1$ and $i-q$.  The corresponding permutation involves a single transposition $(1,i$), so has negative signature.  Thus your determinant is
$$ 
\prod_{j=2}^n (j-q) - \sum_{i=2}^n q(q-1) \prod_{j: 2 \le j \le n, j \ne i} (j-q) 
$$